# In Redis is it possible to find all hashes with a key containing a specified value?

Tags: redis, jedis

I am using Jedis, and new to both that and Redis itself.  I have db that stores hashes, and need to find all keys in the db that contain an entry with a specified key and a specified value.   EG: "find all hashes in the db that have key/value of STATUS=ERROR".   Is this possible in Jedis?  From what I can tell from googling, hscan will find keys in a specified hash.

More generally, by way of teaching me to fish, any pointers for where to look this up?  It seems there is no real jedis api doc, and not even the Redis doc itself seems to have nothing on hscan.

Comment: "the Redis doc itself seems to have nothing on hscan" - HSCAN is very similar to SCAN. So similar that it doesn't make sense to make a dedicated description for it. https://redis.io/commands/hscan

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, you can use `HSCAN` to find the specified key-value pair from a hash. Also, you need to use the `SCAN` command to find all hashes.

However, this is **NOT** an efficient solution. In order to achieve your goal efficiently, you need to build an extra index, i.e. use a Redis `SET` to save keys of all hashes that have the specified key-value pair.

```
HSET hash1 STATUS ERROR
// ...
// HSET other members
// ...
// add it to index
SADD status:error hash1
// get all hashes have the specified key-value pair
SMEMBERS status:error
```

**UPDATE:**

As @Itamar Haber mentioned in the comments, if you have many records in the `SET`, you should use `SSCAN` to get these members. Since in this case, `SMEMBERS` might block Redis for a long time.

Comment: Nit picking - you'd actually want to use `SSCAN` instead of `SMEMBERS` for all the obvious reasons ;)